# Least probability of collisions using rgb as a hash map

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to rewrite a short utility library, to get it working with the Brave browser (My actual question isn't about brave per se.)

[canvas-color-tracker](https://github.com/vasturiano/canvas-color-tracker) - [example of it being used](https://vasturiano.github.io/canvas-color-tracker/example/canvas-medium.html) and [src/index.js](https://github.com/vasturiano/canvas-color-tracker/blob/master/src/index.js)  is short

**The HTML canvas is used for mouse over and clicks to determine what object is under the cursor.**

To use it with circles, you register your circle to get a color, then draw the circle in that color. Then to determine what is under the cursor, you get the color with [getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData).

The trouble is what to do about anti-aliasing, the browser doesn't allow that to be turned off, and I want to be able to return nothing rather than collide with another uninvolved circle when it's edges blend into another color)

---

**Assuming the anti-aliasing blends linearly** How to create an ordering of points in 8bit RGB space, such that the minimum number of points are colinear without knowing the final total number of points? **What is a reasonable heuristic for this?**

---

Addendum, I am doing this because Brave will choose a color channel at random and randomly vary the lowest bit of it - [bit fiddling](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/9591) as a privacy feature prevent fingerprinting.

I figure that if I improve on the algorithm as well as drop the lowest bits for Brave, the maintainer will be happy to use my version (or I will just use my fork anyway)

Comment: I doubt this is answerable without knowing exactly what antialiasing method is in use, and what transformations might be applied to the image.  Might it be subject to zoom/crop/scale/resizing?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What is the input and what is the desired output?

Comment: I rewrote the description to include my context, of what I am trying to do